# How do I TranslateTransform an border to a new location

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 5 Images and a border, when the user clicks an image, I want the border to slide over until it is directly over the Image that was clicked.
I am having a hard time figuring out this transform stuff.  I am good with C# but new to wpf.   I am quite certain that the translatetransform is what I need, but I have no idea how to implement it.  Can someone show me, or point me to a good tutorial on this topic.

```
var RT=new TranslateTransform(90,0);
SelectBorder.RenderTransform = RT;
SelectBorder.BeginAnimation(...//I don't know what a dependency object is
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590761.aspx), it has a full example of how to use the method. (Also you would start the animation on the transform not the Border)

Comment: Not a very good tutorial, but it is helpful.  There is nothing on how to move it though, and that is what I am really struggling on.  Size is easy, but there is no location property

Comment: @K'Leg: Just animate the [`XProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.xproperty.aspx) or [`YProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.yproperty.aspx) of the transform.